# Random access denied errors on User Extensions

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When using extensions in the Graph API:

```cs
graphUser = graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(graphUser).Result;

OpenTypeExtension newExtension = new OpenTypeExtension()
{
    ExtensionName = "CustomName",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    { { "CustomID", user.CustomID }
    }
};

graphClient.Users[graphUser.UserPrincipalName]
    .Extensions
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(newExtension)
    .Wait();
```

I randomly get these errors:

```
Code: AccessDenied
Message: Access Denied
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I can't seem to find a correlation.
When I step trough the code in the debugger it works more often then if I run it without interruption. But if I add a sleep between the lines (to account for processing delay), it doesn't fix the issue.

The application has all the required rights to access the API.

The issue isn't solely in the `POST`, but also on the `GET` as illustrated in the code sample below which results in the same error.

```cs
User user = graphClient.Users[userName]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;

user.Extensions = graphClient.Users[userName]
    .Extensions
    .Request()
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
```

Does anyone have experience with this issue? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I figured out that once the errors start showing, the user needs to be deleted. Errors on one user don't necessarily mean errors on another user.

EDIT 2:

I also posted this as an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/199). Here you can find more information about this problem. It's now labeled as a bug.

Comment: It shouldn't change the behavior because the .Result waits for the action to complete. It might be more efficient but it is not a solution that I can implement unfortunately due to the nature of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the User Principal Name is a cached reference.
Since I was running tests, meaning recreating the same test user a lot, the reference UPN was pointing to the old user object resulting in the Access Denied errors.

**The issue can be avoided by using the Id of the object, like this:**

```
 graphClient.Users[graphUser.Id]
    .Extensions
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(newExtension)
    .Wait();
```

I believe the team is going to fix the reference bug, but I can't speak for them of course. In either case I would recommend using the Id attribute to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for helping us identify this issue and posting the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the test, when we create a new user in Azure Active Directory, it seems that there is some delay we can operate for that user. Even the user is returned successfully when I using the Graph to filter the user, it still may failed when I add the extension to that user.

For this issue, I added a line of addition code to make the current thread sleep and then it works.

```
var userPrincipalName = "userPrincipalName8@adfei.onmicrosoft.com";
var graphUser = new User() { AccountEnabled = true, MailNickname = "MailNickname", UserPrincipalName = userPrincipalName, DisplayName = "userPrincipalName", PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile() { Password = "islkdifde123!", ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false } };

graphUser = graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(graphUser).Result;

OpenTypeExtension newExtension = new OpenTypeExtension()
{
    ExtensionName = "CustomName",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    { 
        { "CustomID", "abc" }
    }
};

Thread.Sleep(4000);
graphClient.Users[graphUser.UserPrincipalName]
    .Extensions
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(newExtension)
    .Wait();
```

However the detailed error message for this issue should be `code=ResourceNotFound,message=User not found`. Please check whether the error is same and this workaround is helpful.

Comment: I did already try this solution, but to be thorough I tried it again. Unfortunately it resulted in the same Access Denied error.

Comment: Is it helpful to set more long time for thread sleeping? Would you mind sharing the detailed error message which you can track it with Fiddler?